# Remove last comma from array after obtaining database results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, implode

I'm trying to list data from my database, and I need to use variables inside of my array, but when echoing it I want it to remove the last comma but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$forum_usersonline = $kunaiDB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_loggedin = '1'");
                while($forum_usersonline_fetch = $forum_usersonline->fetch_array()) {
                    $usersonlineuname = $forum_usersonline_fetch["user_name"];
                    $onlinelist = array($usersonlineuname, ' ');
                    echo implode($onlinelist, ',');
                }
```

It always returns with `user1, user2,` so how should I do it?

Comment: You are using implode in wrong way use this implode(',',$onlinelist);

Comment: @SunilPachlangia That makes no difference in this case.

Comment: @EliasNicolas it's the only way I know of adding commas after each variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can do this job easily in sql. If your database is mysql try following

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(user_name) as user_name FROM users WHERE user_loggedin = '1'
```

or if your database is postgres try following

```
SELECT string_agg(user_name, ',') as user_name FROM users WHERE user_loggedin = '1'
```

above query result return comma separated user_name.

Comment: This actually worked surprisingly well. I had no idea you could do this in a simple query, I appreciate it!

Comment: I agree with this answer. The best way is to do this at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `chop();` which removes characters from the right end of a string.

An example:

```
<?php
$str = "Random String Ending With,";
echo $str . "<br>";
echo chop($str,",");
?>
```

Or you could use `rtrim();` like:

```
<?php
$str = "Random String Ending With,";
echo $str . "<br>";
echo rtrim($str,',');
?>
```

Or you could also use `substr` like:

```
<?php
$str = "Random String Ending With,";
echo substr($str,0,-1)."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: When I try this it removes all the commas, and not the the comma of the last result.

Comment: @P.Nick If a it is a string that we are talking about then it should only remove the last one. I'll add a fiddle in a moment.

Comment: Better use `rtrim` instead or you can use `substr` instead

Comment: @Uchiha Noted. that's what came into my mind at that time. I'll edit my answer in a moment. cheers

Answer (score 0):

use `rtrim(string,',')`

For reference goto http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_rtrim.asp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're doing the `implode` inside the `while` loop, it should be done outside after building your final array. This is what I would do:

```
$forum_usersonline = $kunaiDB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_loggedin = 1");

while ($row = $forum_usersonline->fetch_array()) {
    $onlinelist[] = $row["user_name"];
}

echo implode($onlinelist, ",");
```

However, this should not be the case as you should be using `CONCAT` when doing your database query.